# How can i export email list of undelivered mail from mailgun dashboard?

Tags: php

I want to export csv of undeliverd email form mailgun dashboard.please help me if any option available.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to use Mailgun API and retrieve the "suppressions" lists - bounces, unsubscribes, and complaints. See the Mailgun docs with examples - https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-suppressions.html#suppressions

Otherwise, Mailgun does not offer such functionality from the dashboard. You can just view the statistics and the suppressions lists.